# Missing Eridian Resonator

Tags: borderlands-3

I completed Chapter 10 of Borderlands 3 in a friend's game. I guess I didn't know that I needed to pick up an Eridian Resonator in the Vault of the Rampager.

Is there a way to acquire an Eridian Resonator, short of waiting until I do a second play through?

Comment: Have you tried returning to the vault and trying to collect it again?

Comment: Yes. There was nothing that could be picked up except the contents of a couple of chests.

Comment: have you tried using the resonator at all? It's possible that the game could've given it to you as the quest was completed?

Comment: Oh yeah, multiple times.